# choosing language to work on very large text files (up to some terabytes)

Tags: java, python, bash, awk

I am working on a project which uses text files (.txt) for input, reading them line by line but this files can go as large as 1 terabytes. I know some languages/technologies which I used for similar problems, those are Java, Bash, Awk, and Python. But I don't know which one can work with such large file, and what kind on tricks and tweaks will be needed.

Comment: It seems that if you broke the file into pieces during your processing of it that you could use any of those tools.

Comment: The way is the goal. Or in this case, technique beats tool.

Comment: You don't need tricks or tweaks, unless text line lengths are larger than the chosen language & op system can handle, which is unlikely, or unless you are trying to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: If you've written programs for similar problems, you should be able to test this in less time than it takes to ask this question. For example, in Python, `with open('giantfile.txt') as f:` `for i, line in enumerate(f): pass` `print(i)`. Does it work? Does it use a lot of memory? Does it take forever and a day? If the answers are yes, no, no, then you know that Python can work with such a large file without any tricks. Then try the same with Awk, etc.

Comment: I don't have giant file right now. But I might face that situation. So I asked which language will be able to handle such big file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you process your file line by line and you assemble some statistics, it doesn't really matter what tool you choose.

Java has some advantage in terms of speed, compared to scripting languages, but in the end it will be a difference only by a constant factor. What matters the most is the algorithm that you use to process the file.